# ASP.NET MVC Globalization JQuery.Validate local and remote difference

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, globalization, unobtrusive-validation

Model:

```
[Required]
[StringLength(200, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Messages), ErrorMessageResourceName = "ErrorMessageResourceName_StringLengthMax")]
[Display(Name = "Profile_City", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Messages))]
public string City { get; set; }
```

View:

```
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.City, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-sm-6" })
            <div class="col-sm-18">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.City, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", autocomplete = "off" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.City, string.Empty, new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
```

Global.asax:

```
  protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpCookie cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["language"];
        if (cookie != null && cookie.Value != null)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(cookie.Value);
            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(cookie.Value);
        }
        else
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
        }
    }
```

Cookie value can be de-DE or en-US

The problem when i test the application and forgot the write a city:
Local with DE language:
The Error Message is "Das Feld "Stadt" ist erforderlich." (ok)
Local with US language:
The Error Message is "The City field is required." (ok)
Remote with US language:
The Error Message is "The City field is required." (ok)
Remote with DE language:
The Error Message is "The Stadt field is required." (not ok)

It is a mix between english and german. "Stadt" is german which is ok. But "The ... field is required" is english.
If i write more than 200 letters than StringLength Validator shows a correctly error message in german with remote DE-language.

I use jquery 1.10.2 and jQuery Validation Plugin 1.11.1

Do i need to write the Required Message manually? For Local everything works fine automatically.

Comment: Your not using a resource file for the `[Required]` attribute (as your doing for the `[StringLength]` attribute). Note that the "Stadt " comes from the fact that the attribute formats the error message based on the `[Display]` attribute which is using your resource file

Comment: Yes. I'm not sure if i need this. Because local it works "Das Feld "Stadt" ist erforderlich." Why?

Comment: Not sure. Is the culture in your machine local German?

Comment: Yes i use a german machine

Comment: And I assume the culture on the production server is US (or invariant)?